# How can I show only terms from a certain vocabulary in a view summary?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a View that has a contextual filter for Taxonomy terms... I have selected that if the parameter is not given just show a summary, but I want that summary to show only terms of a certain vocabulary... is that possible?

**UPDATE:** Just to be clear. I'm selecting nodes that has two fields that points to different vocabularies, so in the summary the view is showing all the terms form both vocabularies, I just want to show the terms that are only on one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing. I found my answer here: http://drupal.org/node/1243488#comment-4843640

It's not very intuitive, but it works.

Comment: Hello Lonita, thanks a lot. As you said it is not very intuitive (there is a lot of thigs to study about Drupal).

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this isn't trivial to accomplish.

In this case you're probably better off specifying a default argument for the vocabulary you want.